# Login to icq account to receive messages from contact #12345678

Tags: php, icq

Is there a way to have a php-script running, that does the following things:
- log into icq-account
- receive all (if any) messages from an existing contact #12345678 and
- write those messages into an array like e.g. $messages = array();

**edit**
I'd like to have answer like: "bla" is good, active community, frequently updated, as icq changes a lot their internals,...

Answer (score 3):

Let's see: http://www.google.com/search?q=icq+php

First result of that: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3663-PHP-Communicate-with-ICQ-users.html

> This class can be used to communicate with other ICQ users.
>
> It can:
>
> - Establish connections to an ICQ server using non-blocking sockets
> - Authenticate as a given user
> - Receive offline messages
> - Send and receive messages
> - (...)

I'd say that's the code you are looking for.

Comment: @Jeriko: That sequence of letters seems to be slightly filtered here. Although it surprised me at first, I can understand it - being nicer to new users and all.

Comment: Ah yes, I just realised it's blocked when you add .com to the end.. Don't really understand why; it might be a bit obnoxious, but it gets the point across :) Sometimes people expect all the work to be done for them without trying at all.

Comment: Yeah, but the line between "utfg" and "stfu noob" is narrower than it looks. Using "did you google for it," the potential for misunderstanding is lessened. (I'm not advocating PC; just noting that for certain classes of questions, you're likely to get a prefab answer (UTFG, UTFjquery, etc.). We're seriously offtopic by now; shall we continue on Meta?)

Comment: hey, come on.. stackoverflow is my new google.. i didn't find it here, so i asked. ;-)

but serious now. i'd like to have answers like: "PHP ICQ is good, active community, frequently updated, ..." answers i won't get by just flying over the google result.. (maybe ill add this to the question)

Comment: @justastefan: good point about "word on the street". On the other hand, if you do your due dilligence, you'll ask a better question and will get better answers (in this case, something like "which PHP ICQ library would you recommend? I've experimented with foo, but bar has much better documentation, while baz seems actively developed")

Answer (score 0):

There are many classes for that (google: php icq), but they are quite unstable because of restricted protocol. You also can use classes for Jabber (they work more properly) and receive messages from icq through the transport.